# How does someone “simply avoid” an overrun attempt?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, movement, attack

I have a question regarding *[Overrun](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialAttacks.htm#overrun)* special attack in D&D 3.5. The rule says that, the defender can "*simply avoid me*", but it doesn't clarify if he has to perform any action or roll in order to achieve that. Is that so, that the defender only says "*I'm avoiding!*" and that's it? Is there no need for any roll? Does it mean that I can pass through the defender as he wasn't even there? Does the defender stay all the time on the same square as before while avoiding?

> Opponent Avoids? The defender has the option to simply avoid you. If he avoids you, he doesn’t suffer any ill effect and you may keep moving (You can always move through a square occupied by someone who lets you by.) The overrun attempt doesn’t count against your actions this round (except for any movement required to enter the opponent’s square). If your opponent doesn’t avoid you, move to Step 3.

Thanks for your help and sorry if it is so simple.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When a typical creature makes against a foe an [overrun](http://dndsrd.net/specialAttacks.html#overrun) attempt, that foe can opt to avoid that creature. That foe makes no roll to avoid the creature, the foe stays in its space, and the foe suffers no ill effects. The creature that made the overrun attempt continues moving normally. (The special attack overrun says specifically that the creature can make the overrun attempt during its move action: "In general, you cannot take a standard action during a move; this is an exception" (*Player's Handbook* 157).)

So, yes, if a goblin warrior stands between Regdar and the goblin warlord, when Regdar makes the overrun attempt against the goblin warrior to get to the goblin warlord, the goblin warrior can just say, "Right this way, sir!" and let Regdar go by.

It takes a feat like [Improved Overrun](http://dndsrd.net/featsAll.html#improved-overrun) (*PH* 96) or a special ability for the creature that's making the overrun attempt to force the foe *not* to avoid it!

---

***Note:*** The Player's Handbook *errata eliminates from the special attack charge the option of making an overrun attempt.*

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation with examples great answer :)